# SQLite auto increment on INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, cordova

I have a SQLite database and I need to mark any new record and any modified record with an ever increasing counter. I have to avoid race conditions

Those are my two queries I'm using at the moment:

**Insert:**

```
INSERT INTO customer (id, name, counter) VALUES (myId, "blablabla", ((SELECT MAX(counter) FROM customer) + 1))
```

**Update:**

```
UPDATE customer SET name = "blablabla", counter = (SELECT MAX(counter) FROM customer) + 1 WHERE id = myId
```

Is this safe? I'm using SQLite on a Cordova mobile app

If not, what's the best way to do it? Can I declare `counter` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` and have just those two queries?

**Insert:**

```
INSERT INTO customer (id, name) VALUES (myId, "blablabla")
```

**Update:**

```
UPDATE customer SET name = "blablabla", counter = (SELECT MAX(counter) FROM customer) + 1 WHERE id = myId
```

Comment: SQLite and MySQL are two entirely different things.

Comment: let's go for SQLite then... BTW brilliant -> https://github.com/ConsenSys/dapp-store-contracts/blob/master/contracts/ReviewModel.sol

Comment: SQLite is a good choice for embedding in applications since it doesn't require a server process.

Comment: Ok good, but is it correct what I'm doing? Have a look at the question

Comment: `SELECT MAX(x)` is not going to be immune to race conditions. Why don't you make a sequence generator?

Comment: It's hard to say if you are correct because it's not clear what you are looking to achieve.  For example, if I add records 1 and 2, then update 2, what would the counter values be?

Comment: @DanBracuk then record 2 would have its own counter field updated as the current maximum counter value + 1. What I'm trying to do is to mark using "timestamps" not related to any notion of time, just a monotonic increasing value which marks any record being created or updated

Comment: If I understand this right. You want to update the counter to +1 whenever it's being updated?. For ex: New user, counter = 1, updated name then counter =2, updated lname, counter = 3. Is this for "every" activity for that user?

Comment: @Isaiah3015 exactly, plus, it should be updated on creation of a new record. The value in this case is again the maximum value so far for the table

Comment: Your approach is fine. However, If I were in your position, I would default to counter 1 for new users and then do a trigger for the updates. But since you have front end app, this will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a TABLE that hold nothing but the value of the counter call this each time you add a new record or update and increase it by a value of 1 and write that value back to the TABLE with an update I am not sure what you do when you delete a record but the same thing as above and just decrease the counter value by 1

If you do not min could you tell us why a record need to have an ID and a psudo ID  it does not matter what the true ID is OR am I missing what your are doing I am talking about Sqlite only

Comment: I solved the delete problem buy transforming a delete into an update. Basically, instead of actually deleting a record I update a "deleted" field. Every "select" query is selecting ANDing with deleted = 0